# Linear system of equations over $\mathbb{Z}_7$ with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra

> \begin{align*}
> (3a^2-b)x-2y &= 5, \\
> by &= 2,
> \end{align*}
> where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_7$ are parameters and $x,y\in\mathbb Z_7$ are unknown.

So I was trying to figure out this matrix, the field is $\mathbb{Z}_7$ (integers modulo $7$)

I need to find all the pairs of (a,b) so the matrix will have more than 1 solution. (also, Find how many solutions there is for each pair).

so first thing first, if $b=0$ then we have no answers, so I found out $b$ must not be equal to $0$.

and then I'm stuck and I don't know what to do more.
I found out that for $b=3$ and $a=1$ which gets a solution, but it's only $1$ solution.

by my calculation, there is always $0$ solution or only $1$.
never "more than one".
What am I doing wrong?

Sorry if this question is kinda stupid I'm a newbie.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

When $b\neq 0$, it has a multiplicative inverse $b^{-1}$ in $\mathbb Z_7$, so you get $y=2b^{-1}$ from the second equation. Substitute this into the first equation and you are left with one linear equation in one variable.

Comment: Yes I did it before posting the question here and I get the following answer :                        x=(5b+4)/(3ba^2 + 6b^2) and y = 2/b , but I still don't know what to do next.           because we have a and b and x.

Comment: Make sure you don't divide by $0$ by doing further case distinctions.

Comment: yeah I didn't devide because b must not be 0.

Comment: I was referring to $(3a^2-b)$. You divided by that.

Comment: so what I need to do is like "Anurag A" said , I have more than 1 answer when the first line equals to 0 right? so its when b=2 and a^2 = 2/3 but a is in z7 , so there is always 1 solution , I got it right?

Answer (score 1):

From the second equation you have $b$ must be invertible (otherwise no solution), hence $y=2b^{-1}$. Then from the first equation we get
$$(3a^2-b)x=5+4b^{-1}.$$
If $3a^2-b$ is invertible, then you have exactly one solution. But if $3a^2-b \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$, then you may have no solution or more than one solution. This depends on what $5+4b^{-1}$ is. For **more** than one solution, we want
\begin{align*}
3a^2 & \equiv b \pmod{7}\\
5+4b^{-1} & \equiv 0 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}
From the latter you get $b \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$. Consequently,
$$3a^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{7} \implies a^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}.$$
But this has no solutions ($3$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $7$). Thus there are NO values for which this system has more than one solution.

To have NO solutions, we would require $b \not\equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ and $3a^2 \equiv b \pmod{7}$. So when $b=3$ and $a=1,6$, then we will have NO solution (you should recheck your work). Likewise when $b=5$ and $a=2,5$ OR when $b=6$ and $a=3,4$ there are NO solutions.

Comment: Thank you , you made it very clear!!